# C# protected property or field

Tags: c#, properties

Do you think it's better to always make protected class members an auto-implemented protected property to keep isolation or make it protected field is enough?

```
protected bool test { get; set; }
```

or

```
protected bool test;
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Generally, you should use autoproperties - this allow you to easily add verification, or anything else you need later on. This is especially important if the protected member will be used by classes outside your assembly, as adding such code won't break your contract with them, whereas changing a field to a method or property will.

Comment: How does the use of autoproperties make it easy to add verification?

Comment: You can change the autoproperties to normal properties later on, and add whatever code you want, and people using your dll won't have to recompile to use the updated assemblies.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is old, but I would answer it based on the scope of the value as well as where it needs to be initialized or written to.  I try to use the tightest scope possible.  Hopefully the following will make it more clear on how to decide:

**Protected values:**  This assumes the value only needs to be accessed by the base class and/or the inheriting class, and not by any outside code...

1. When the inheriting class has to read, but never has to modify the value:

   - If the value can be written once in the constructor of the base class, use the following, which prevents the inheriting class from writing to it, and goes a step further and only allows it to be set in the constructor:

     `protected readonly bool test;`
   - If the value can be written to in a different method other than the constructor, but still only in the base class, use the following, which prevents the inheriting class from writing to it, but allows it to read:

     `protected bool Test { get; private set; }`
2. When the inheriting class can modify the value, use the following, which allows both the inheriting class and the base class to write to it at any point:

   `protected bool test;`

**Private values:**  This assumes the value only needs to be accessed from within the class it is declared in.

1. If it can only be set once in the constructor, use:

   `readonly bool test;`
2. If it can be set anywhere in the class, use:

   `bool test;`

Also, don't forget that if you declare it as a property, it should use PascalCase.  If you declare it as a member variable, it should use camelCase.  This will make it easier for other developers to understand the scope.

Answer (score 8):

The suggested practice is to **make it a property**.  The signature changes depending on whether it's a field or a property, which can cause problems if you're crossing assemblies.  If you make it a property to begin with, you'll never have this problem.  (often later you want to add logic when the property is read or written.)

In C#, auto-implementing the property is so easy, there's no reason not to do it.

Also, it makes things more clear.  If it is really meant to be used by the outside world as part of the functioning of the object, make it a property.  Otherwise, a future programmer might wonder if you made a field protected instead of private by accident.

Answer (score 3):

property, backed by a private field.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148132/property-visibility-in-abstract-class) might be useful

Comment: What's the actual advantage over a protected field?

Comment: encapsulation for one, and the ability to break the debugger when it is accessed makes it useful too.

Comment: One advantage is the ability to do property-change notification with, for example, INotifyPropertyChanged.  In general, this approach (protected property backed by a private field) promotes encapsulation, i.e. information-hiding. Don't reveal implementation unless you have a good reason for doing so.  (I'm assuming the question centers on protected properties because some inheritance is involved.)

Comment: To be frank, I don't run into many cases in my own code where I want a class to be inherited while exposing a protected value, but it's certainly realistic.  While my immediate reaction is to wrap it in a property, a protected relationship is  pretty intimate already so I wonder how much leverage wrapping it really buys you here.  I guess I'd agree on wrapping, but I have to admit to mixed feeling here.

Comment: @StevenSudit: What about exposing a reference to a mutable object owned by the base?  If an inheritable collection exposes `protected List<T> contents`, the semantics of `contents.Add(someNewItem)` are IMHO much clearer than if `contents` is exposed as a property.  Exposing the data store limits the ability of future base-class versions to use something better, but may allow derived classes to do many useful things that would otherwise be impossible or impractical.  Exposure as an auto-property is IMHO worst-of-both-worlds, since it would basically tell those writing derived classes that...

Comment: ...they may or may not be getting a reference to the "real" data store, thus discouraging them from writing code that would assume it has the real one, but since code that relied upon getting the real backing store would work as long as the property returned that and might not be readily modifiable to work with a property that does anything else, use of an autoproperty wouldn't really reserve any more flexibility for the base-class author than would use of a field.

Answer (score 3):

You should never allow direct access to a member variable from outside your class. Either use an auto-generated property or a property with a backing field. If you allow direct access, it can lead to some really bad debugging headaches when multiple methods change that value in a derivation chain and you don't know which one is causing the bug.